Child is not sending model to parent
I am a bit puzzled by this behavior ...
I am trying to update model value in parent from child ...
parent:
<template>
  <form-component1 v-model="formData1" :errors="errors.form1" />
  <button @click="submitData">Submit</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, watch } from 'vue';
import FormComponent1 from './FormComponent1.vue';
import { defineEmits } from 'vue';

const errors = reactive({
  form1: {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  }
});

const formData1 = reactive({
  email: '',
  name: ''
});

const emit = defineEmits(['submit-data']);

function submitData() {
  console.log("Submitting FormData:", formData1);
  emit('submit-data', { ...formData1 });
}

// Add a watch for debugging to see if formData1 is updated
watch(formData1, (newVal) => {
  console.log("Parent formData1 changed:", newVal);
}, { deep: true });
</script>

Child:
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="localData.name" placeholder="Name">
    <div v-if="errors.name">{{ errors.name }}</div>
    <input v-model="localData.email" placeholder="Email">
    <div v-if="errors.email">{{ errors.email }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch, watchEffect, defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: Object,
  errors: Object
});

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
const localData = ref({ ...props.modelValue });

// React to external changes in modelValue
watch(() => props.modelValue, (newVal) => {
  localData.value = { ...newVal };
}, { deep: true });

// Emit local changes to the parent
watchEffect(() => {
  emit('update:modelValue', { ...localData.value });
});
</script>

But I can see those values in the watchEffect in child .. but nothing is going to parent ...
Working example: VuePlayground

v-model reassigns a value, this requires formData1 to be a ref instead of reactive object:
const formData1 = ref({
  email: '',
  name: ''
});

function submitData() {
  emit('submit-data', { ...formData1.value });
}

It may be necessary to merge an object instead of creating a new one to avoid undesirable state updates when localData state is synchronised (a demo):
watch(() => props.modelValue, (newVal) => {
  Object.assign(localData.value, newVal);
}, { deep: true });

A cleaner and more efficient way would be to discard local state in a child unless it's needed for some other reason, e.g. undo, and do mutations only in a parent. This is one of the forms that two-way data binding can take The changes are easily trackable in devtools and good for performance, no excessive objects are created (a demo).
In a child it's basically:
<input :value="props.value.name" @input="emit('changeForm', { name: $event.target.value })">

In a parent:
<child :value="formData" @changeForm="Object.assign(formData, $event)">


works too.. but I like the other one better :) in my actual implementation (not in this demo) it doesn't work as nice as the one above .. anyway - thx again

@Mr.P This is about following best practices, not just a matter of taste. The idea behind v-model and two-way binding in general is to avoid prop mutation as this results in messy data flow, see https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props . This is what we had 10y ago with Angular 1.x and it didn't work well on the large scale. If the answer doesn't work for you for some reason, consider updating the question

the code looks a lot more cleaner with the solution above... can you please share your playground link pls?

@Mr.P It's hard to send playground link through comments, added it to the post. The part that likely was troublesome here is that localData.value= can cause circular state update when syncing the states. This is about working cleaner, not looking cleaner. Mutating a prop can be a hell to debug and optimize. I'd suggest to check the story behind two-way binding in its current state and why it became the thing in Angular and React and then Vue which borrowed from both, in case you didn't, there's a reason why they are dogmatic about emitting an event

@Mr.P In a case like this one a cleaner and more effiicient way I'm using is to discard localData state so you don't need to sync two of them but mutate only in a parent, unless there's logic that needs that (edit undo, etc). I.e. in a child it's basically <input :value="props.formData.name" @input="emit('changeForm', { name: $event } and in a parent <child :formData="formData" @changeForm="Object.assign(formData, $event)">. The changes are easily trackable in devtools and good for performance, makes sense for complex nested forms

lemme check that one ... if you can provide an example in the playground, I would owe you a big one :)

@Mr.P I added it. The selling point is that atomic changes can be debugged in changeForm listener and seen in event list in devtools, a watcher may be not enough to untangle when this goes wrong

the links is not working :(

hmmm I am struggling a bit still.. I created a better pllayground demo... would you please look at it ? thx a lot https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rj7ysb?file=src%2FDialogComponent.vue

See console for errors. There's no basicDetails in a parent. You're using comps instead of  so props and events are different. Third-party comps commonly follow v-model convention, so it should be <InputText :modelValue="data.name" @update:modelValue="$emit('changeForm',       @input="$emit('changeForm', { name: $event }, no target.value, see https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

it's nice and very clean this way too .. thx @Estus Flask

Pass the form data as a prop and use toRefs:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
  <form-component1 :data="formData1" :errors="errors.form1" />
  <button @click="submitData">Submit</button>
  <div>{{ formData1 }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import FormComponent1 from './FormComponent1.vue';
import { defineEmits } from 'vue';

const errors = reactive({
  form1: {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  }
});

const formData1 = reactive({
  email: '',
  name: ''
});

const emit = defineEmits(['submit-data']);

function submitData() {
  console.log("Submitting FormData:", formData1);
  emit('submit-data', { ...formData1 });
}

</script>


<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name" placeholder="Name">
    <div v-if="errors.name">{{ errors.name }}</div>
    <input v-model="email" placeholder="Email">
    <div v-if="errors.email">{{ errors.email }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {toRefs} from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  errors: Object,
  data: Object
});

const {name, email} = toRefs(props.data);

</script>


This results in deeply mutating a prop, which is discouraged
